# How can I see function arguments in IPython Notebook Server 3?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've recently switched to IPython Notebook 3 (3.1.0-cbccb68 to be exact), the Anaconda version. Previously when I typed a function and opened a parenthesis like this:

```
time.sleep()
```

and if the cursor was between the parentheses then I would get a contextual overlay menu that displayed the function arguments. Now I don't see it, and although I've searched, I can't find out how I can turn on this functionality.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

In 1.0, the functionality was bound to `(` and `tab` and `shift-tab`, in 2.0 `tab` was deprecated but still functional in some unambiguous cases completing or inspecting were competing in many cases. Recommendation was to always use `shift-Tab`. `(` was also added as deprecated as confusing in Haskell-like syntax to also push people toward Shift-Tab as it works in more cases. in 3.0 the deprecated bindings have been remove in favor of the official, present for 18+ month now `Shift-Tab`.

So press `Shift-Tab`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why that was so challenging to find online.

Comment: Because we are bad a documenting things, and what to search for is not clear :-)

Comment: maybe at least a hover tooltip would help to know that such tooltip thing even exists :)

Comment: For some reason i cannot get it to work on a Mac. I used to be able to hover but pressing shift-tab does not work for me.

Comment: If it isn't working, makes sure the module is imported. I spent 20 minutes wondering why it wasn't working for me, and realized I hadn't run the cell with the import.

Comment: What's "the module"?

Comment: Run this command on the terminal, open a new jupyter notebook afterwards, and it works : pip install pyreadline

Comment: what is the name of this action?  can it be bound to some other shortcut.

Comment: In case anyone is sitting there wondering why nothing happens sometimes when you hit shift-tab (like me), it is likely because you have to run the relevant package or module import first.

Answer (score 58):

Try `Shift-Tab-Tab` a bigger documentation appears, than with `Shift-Tab`. It's the same but you can scroll down.

`Shift-Tab-Tab-Tab` and the tooltip will linger for 10 seconds while you type.

`Shift-Tab-Tab-Tab-Tab` and the docstring appears in the pager (small part at the bottom of the window) and stays there.

Answer (score 33):

Adding screen shots(examples) and some more context for the answer of @Thomas G.

#### if its not working please make sure if you have executed code properly. In this case make sure `import pandas as pd` is ran properly before checking below shortcut.

Place the cursor in middle of parenthesis `()` before you use shortcut.

## `shift + tab`

> Display short document and few params

[image]

## `shift + tab + tab`

> Expands document with scroll bar

[image]

## `shift + tab + tab + tab`

> Provides document with a Tooltip: "will linger for 10secs while you type". which means it allows you write params and waits for 10secs.

[image]

## `shift + tab + tab + tab + tab`

> It opens a small window in bottom with option(top righ corner of small window) to open full documentation in new browser tab.

[image]

Comment: there is no `shift + tab+ tab+ tab+ tab+ tab`?

Comment: @Shakeel This does work for many functions but it doesn't for others. For example, using only pandas, in 


   `oo.groupby('Edition','NOC').agg(['min','max'])`


Shift + Tab works only inside the groupby function but not the agg function. I would like to know how we can get help for the various available parameters of agg.

Answer (score 1):

Shift-Tab works for me to view the dcoumentation

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is about IPython Notebook, it's still a top Google result for Jupyter Lab as well. For Jupyter Lab >= 2.2.9, there is a dedicated **Show Contextual Help** window you can enable from the Help menu. This window will persist and show you the function documentation for whichever function inside which your cursor lays.

[image: Jupyter Lab with Show Contextual Help window open]