# How can I see function arguments in Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I was using jupyter notebook. Now I am using [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/).

I wonder how to display what argument (also, description) of specific function in Zeppelin.

In Jupyter, it is `Shift-Tab`

My question similar to [How can I see function arguments in IPython Notebook Server 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855169/how-can-i-see-function-arguments-in-ipython-notebook-server-3), but for [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/).